# string argument in template specialization in C++

Tags: c++

In the following code, why the 's' after the string "hello" in the last line is necessary in order to deduce the type of the argument? It is an explicit casting to a string in c++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T addition(T const& a, T const& b){ return a + b;}

template <class T, size_t N>
T reduce(T const (&array)[N], T value = {}, T (*p)(T const&,T const&) = addition<T>)
{
  T res = value;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    res = p(res,array[i]);
  }
  return res;
}



double multiply(double const& lhs, double const& rhs)
{
    return lhs * rhs;
}

int main()
{
    double pi[]{0.0505, 0.0505, 0.0405};
    double factorial[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
    string concat[]{" ", "world"};
    cout << reduce({1,2,3,4,5}) << endl;
    cout << reduce(pi, 3.0) << endl;
    cout << reduce(factorial, 1.0, multiply) << endl;
    cout << reduce(concat, "hello"s) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `s` in `"hello"s` is the [string literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s). It returns a `std::string`, which means the call to `reduce` will match with the `std::string` array you are passing as the first argument.

Note that the example would not work if you had not written `using namespace std;` (which is not really a good idea to write).

Before C++14, you would typically write `std::string("hello")` instead. Even nowadays, some guidelines prefer to avoid the literals, because you have to first get access to them using `using namespace` and, as a single character, they may be hard to notice.

Comment: `using namespace std::literals;` or `using namespace std::string_literals` is wise. [string.syn](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.syn)

Comment: @Oliv That is debatable! I don't particularly like using literals that construct full objects that may end up even allocating memory (!). In other contexts/languages, that is fine and expected, but in C++, I prefer explicitness when it comes to that.

Answer (score 1):

It's no necessary to deduce the argument, but without the `s` suffix it would not match.

Because `decltype("hello")` is `const char(&)[6]` and that would make `T=const char*`. But that does not match with the first passed argument `concat` of type `std::string(&)[2]` which requires `T` to be `std::string`.

The `s` suffix converts string literal to `std::string`. So yes, it's an explicit cast to a c++ string because in C/C++ string type is not part of the language and instead it's implemented simply as an array.